# Creating a step indicator for devexpress wizard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, wizard

I am developing an application using Winforms and Devexpress Wizard control. Although I searched a lot I couldnt find a way to implement a `step indicator` for the wizard (as shown in the picture below). Any ideas about how I can achieve something like that ?

[image]

Comment: Have you [aksed them](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) how they think it could be done?

Comment: Thanks @JensKloster I will ask them as well

Comment: :) Its how I always do it. The way I see it - its their product, they have an interrest in it having as many features as possible. If the feautre exists - they will tell you right away, and if not - maybe the help you build one.

Comment: You can do UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got from [DevExpress form](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q498362). I was able to implement this as a user control. The only downside is that it's not generic. As you will see, I used checkboxes placed on `LineShape` from `Visual Basic PowerPacks`:

Below is the full code for the logic part:

```
public partial class WizardStepControl : UserControl
{
    public WizardStepControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetStepCurrent(int step)
    {
        switch (step)
        {
            case 1:
                SetCurrent(step1);

                break;

            case 2:
                SetCurrent(step2);
                break;

            case 3:
                SetCurrent(step3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SetStepChecked(int step)
    {
        switch (step)
        {
            case 1:
                SetChecked(step1);
                break;

            case 2:
                SetChecked(step2);
                break;

            case 3:
                SetChecked(step3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SetStepNext(int step)
    {
        switch (step)
        {
            case 1:
                SetNext(step1);
                break;

            case 2:
                SetNext(step2);
                break;

            case 3:
                SetNext(step3);
                break;
        }
    }


    private void SetChecked(CheckEdit checkBox)
    {
        checkBox.Enabled = true;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureChecked = Resources.wzd_check;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureUnchecked = Resources.wzd_check;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureGrayed = Resources.wzd_check;

    }

    private void SetNext(CheckEdit checkBox)
    {
        checkBox.Enabled = false;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureChecked = Resources.wzd_next;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureUnchecked = Resources.wzd_next;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureGrayed = Resources.wzd_next;
    }

    private void SetCurrent(CheckEdit checkBox)
    {
        checkBox.Enabled = true;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureChecked = Resources.wzd_current;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureUnchecked = Resources.wzd_current;
        checkBox.Properties.PictureGrayed = Resources.wzd_current;
    }
}
```

Place the control in the Wizard header and it will look like this:

[image]